# Is there a general method for testing if the attributes of two objects are equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, comparison

I just wrote a testing script for a project I have in python, and I learned that checking if the values of two objects are equivalent is not as simple as `foo == bar`. For example, I have an object `dashboard` that has a pandas dataframe as an attribute, so I defined its `__eq__` method as:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    vals = [self.__dict__[k] == other.__dict__[k] for k in self.__dict__.keys()]
    vals = [v if isinstance(v, bool) else all(v) for v in vals]
    return all(vals)
```

It compares the dictionaries of each object, and if any of these comparisons yields something other than a boolean (e.g., a dataframe) it applies `all()` to reduce it to a single boolean. I then apply `all()` to this entire list of attribute comparisons to test whether or not every attribute of `self` and `other` are equivalent.

I used this `__eq__` definition in several classes, and also used something similar for a comparison method in my parent Test class. I got my test to work, but I'm curious if there's a more elegant/efficient way to handle this. (Disclaimer: Testing is new to me, as well as OOP in general.)

Comment: you're talking about testing: you should use a testing framework like Unittest, or Pytest; these have lots of built in functions to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a general method for testing equality of objects.

This is partly because custom/arbitrary objects have widely varying interpretations of what equality means. For example, in your code you've defined equality to mean "the values are booleans and/or iterables of booleans and all values agree", but this rule ONLY applies to keys that both dictionaries have in common. Someone else might need to check that a dictionary has all the same keys but doesn't care about the values, or that all keys and all values are identical and of specific datatypes, etc. So, this is left to the user to implement.

Answer (score 0):

to compare dataframes, since you mention this, there is:

```
DataFrame.equals(other)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html